# ImportError: cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram'

Tags: python, бот

вот код:

```
import telegram
import requests
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
# Создание телеграм бота
bot = telegram.Bot(token='6424007515:AAEK3TrVw579AFnGyPXx49F77929c34xY5A')
updater = Updater(token='6424007515:AAEK3TrVw579AFnGyPXx49F77929c34xY5A', use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Обработчик команды /startss
def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Привет! Я бот для получения сигналов по криптовалютам.")

# Обработчик команды /signals
def signals(update, context):
    # Получение цен на BTC и ETH на бирже Bybit
    response_btc_bybit = requests.get("https://www.bybit.com/ru-RU/coin-price/bitcoin/")
    price_btc_bybit = response_btc_bybit.json()["last_price"]
    response_eth_bybit = requests.get("https://www.bybit.com/ru-RU/coin-price/ethereum/")
    price_eth_bybit = response_eth_bybit.json()["last_price"]

    # Получение цен на BTC и ETH на бирже Kucoin
    response_btc_kucoin = requests.get("https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol=BTC-USDT")
    price_btc_kucoin = response_btc_kucoin.json()["data"]["price"]
    response_eth_kucoin = requests.get("https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/market/orderbook/level1?symbol=ETH-USDT")
    price_eth_kucoin = response_eth_kucoin.json()["data"]["price"]

    # Вычисление спреда между ценами на BTC и ETH на биржах Bybit и Kucoin
    spread_btc = float(price_btc_bybit) - float(price_btc_kucoin)
    spread_eth = float(price_eth_bybit) - float(price_eth_kucoin)

    # Отправка сообщения с информацией о спреде
    message = f"Спред между BTC на Bybit и Kucoin: {spread_btc}\nСпред между ETH на Bybit и Kucoin: {spread_eth}"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)

# Добавление обработчиков команд
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
signals_handler = CommandHandler('signals', signals)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(signals_handler)

# Запуск телеграм бота
updater.start_polling()
```

вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kirill2004\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\украина.py", line 3, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
  File "C:\Users\Kirill2004\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from . import filters
  File "C:\Users\Kirill2004\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\filters.py", line 114, in <module>
    from telegram import Chat as TGChat
ImportError: cannot import name 'Chat' from 'telegram' (C:\Users\Kirill2004\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telegram\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Судя по всему библиотека `telegram.ext` не совместима с `telegram`. Ставили всё по инструкциям?

Comment: Какую библиотеку вы юзаете? `python-telegram-bot`?

Comment: python-telegram-bot юзаю

Comment: Я библиотеки из Pycharm ставил